# Conditional: IF post creation date is in the first half OR last half of the year

Tags: date, conditional-content

I'm trying to find a way how to have a simple conditional whereby I can echo something depending on whether the post date is in the first half or last half of the post date year.

Comment: And what have you tried so far?   See https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask.  You're basically looking at extracting the MM out of YYYYMMDD, convert to int, and check if greater than 6.

Comment: I don't know where to start

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this elsewhere and it worked for me...

```
if( (int)get_the_time( 'm' ) <= 6 ) {
    echo 'Some time between January and June.';
} else {
    echo 'Some time between July and December.';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you thinking of something like this?

```
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        if ( absint( get_the_date( 'n' ) ) <= 6 ) {
            // First half of year
            ...
        } else {
            // Second half of year
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: that displays my post an infinite amount of times

Comment: No it wouldn't, unless you copied the whole code into an existing loop.